# Steam Music volume is extremely low -- despite setting it to high?

Tags: steam

I'm trying out Steam Music right now and I"m trying to get the sound to an audible level.

However for some reason it seems the volume seems very muted, despite the fact the volume level bar is at the max.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Check if Steam is at a lower volume in the Windows volume mixer (assuming you're on Windows 7/8).

Comment: Yup, here comes a question about a music player on Arqade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Steam volume is independant from your computer's volume. Make sure your speakers and audio output is turned up.

Also, your volume mixer might be off (assuming you have windows 7-10). To fix this, right click on the white speaker symbol at the right of your taskbar and click volume mixer. In the applications area, you might see that Steam or Steam Music is lower than the grey line (indicating where your speaker is at), at which point you should drag the slider up to the gray bar.